# ng-repeat a quantity inside array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array called `$scope.ticket_array`:

```
$scope.ticket_array = [{"type":"men junior", "quantity":"3"}];
```

How can I use ng-repeat to repeat 3 time accordingly to the quantity value and still be able to show the type as well?

I have tried these:

```
<div ng-repeat = "i in ticket_array">
          <p>{{i.type}}</p>
          <p>{{i.quantity}}</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to access inside the array and repeat the quantity instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the quantity to a function and generate a numeric array and do a ng-repeat over it.

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(parseInt(num.quantity));   
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('studentController', function($scope){
 $scope.ticket_array = [{"type":"men junior", "quantity":"3"}];
 $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(parseInt(num.quantity));   
}        
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController">
     <div ng-repeat = "i in ticket_array">
      <div ng-repeat="j in getNumber(i) track by $index">
          <p>{{i.type}}</p>
          <p>{{j}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry about that i'm still new at this again thank you